# How to load an image in the same package as a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I am making a JPanel display in my eclipse workspace. I have the following code:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("anno.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
```

And to the file "anno.png" in the same package as the class this is in. However when I run this it always shows this message:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A embedded resource (one which reisdes within the Jar or application context) can't normally by accessed using `File`.  Instead, you need to make us of the class loader to do it

Try using...

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("anno.png"));
```

If that doesn't work, try using...

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/anno.png"));
```

Instead

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking in the right place. Java looks for files in a directory that is based off of the user dir, not the class directory.

Solutions:

- Use resources instead of files. The resource directory is based off of the class directory.
- Or find out what the user dir is, but printing out the File absolute path before trying to read in the image.

I favor the former: use resources, not files. i.e., `getClass().getResourceAsStream("anno.png");`

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("anno.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```